# Loop through a character vector and test if a word exists in R?

Tags: r

Basically, I'm trying to loop through a vector of individual words and then im trying to determine if a certain word is contained within that vector. I was trying to do this using base `R`'s `grepl` function, but I can't get it to loop correctly. Here's what I was thinking:

```
stringVector <- c("test", "hello", "bye") # create a vector of words.
testWord <- "test"                        # A word to test the existence of.

# Loop through stringVector and see if the word exists
for(i in length(stringVector)){ 
  logID <- grepl(stringVector[i], testWord, fixed = TRUE)
}
logID
```

So, if this method worked, `logID` would return `TRUE` as the word `test` is contained in `stringVector`. But it is not working correctly, due to (I suspect) an incorrectly written loop.

Any suggestion as to how I would fix this?

Comment: You should not use a loop here. `grepl` is vectorized. You can do `any(grepl(testWord, stringVector, fixed = TRUE))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `%in%` or `==` as it is a fixed string match

```
any(stringVector == testWord)
#[1]  TRUE
```

Or

```
testWord %in% stringVector
```

---

In the OP's loop, the `logID` is getting updated in each iteration.  Also, it is looping on a single element i.e. the last one with `length(stringVector)` - instead, it should be `seq_along`.  We can either initialize the 'logID' as a vector

```
logID <- logical(length(stringVector))
for(i in seq_along(stringVector)){ 
    logID[i] <- grepl(stringVector[i], testWord, fixed = TRUE)
   }

any(logID)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Or another option is

```
logID <- FALSE
for(i in seq_along(stringVector)) {
    if(grepl(stringVector[i], testWord, fixed = TRUE)) logID <- TRUE
   }
```